# Build errors C++ with Poco and Qt Creator

Tags: c++, mingw, static-libraries, qt-creator

I am getting build errors in Qt Creator when trying to build a sample in the Poco library. I used [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14647307/2030199) to build poco with MinGW.

This is the sample I am trying to use:

```
// httpget.cpp
//
// $Id: //poco/1.4/Net/samples/httpget/src/httpget.cpp#3 $
//
// This sample demonstrates the HTTPClientSession and the HTTPCredentials classes.
//
// Copyright (c) 2005-2012, Applied Informatics Software Engineering GmbH.
// and Contributors.
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person or organization
// obtaining a copy of the software and accompanying documentation covered by
// this license (the "Software") to use, reproduce, display, distribute,
// execute, and transmit the Software, and to prepare derivative works of the
// Software, and to permit third-parties to whom the Software is furnished to
// do so, all subject to the following:
//
// The copyright notices in the Software and this entire statement, including
// the above license grant, this restriction and the following disclaimer,
// must be included in all copies of the Software, in whole or in part, and
// all derivative works of the Software, unless such copies or derivative
// works are solely in the form of machine-executable object code generated by
// a source language processor.
//
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT
// SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS OR ANYONE DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE BE LIABLE
// FOR ANY DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
// ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
// DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//


#include "Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPCredentials.h>
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include "Poco/NullStream.h"
#include "Poco/Path.h"
#include "Poco/URI.h"
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include <iostream>


using Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession;
using Poco::Net::HTTPRequest;
using Poco::Net::HTTPResponse;
using Poco::Net::HTTPMessage;
using Poco::StreamCopier;
using Poco::Path;
using Poco::URI;
using Poco::Exception;


bool doRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession& session, Poco::Net::HTTPRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPResponse& response)
{
    session.sendRequest(request);
    std::istream& rs = session.receiveResponse(response);
    std::cout << response.getStatus() << " " << response.getReason() << std::endl;
    if (response.getStatus() != Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)
    {
        StreamCopier::copyStream(rs, std::cout);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Poco::NullOutputStream null;
        StreamCopier::copyStream(rs, null);
        return false;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//    if (argc != 2)
//    {
//        Path p(argv[0]);
//        std::cout << "usage: " << p.getBaseName() << " <uri>" << std::endl;
//        std::cout << "       fetches the resource identified by <uri> and print it to the standard output" << std::endl;
//        return 1;
//    }

    try
    {
        URI uri("http://reddit.com");
        std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
        if (path.empty()) path = "/";

        std::string username;
        std::string password;
        Poco::Net::HTTPCredentials::extractCredentials(uri, username, password);
        Poco::Net::HTTPCredentials credentials(username, password);

        HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
        HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, path, HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
        HTTPResponse response;
        if (!doRequest(session, request, response))
        {
            credentials.authenticate(request, response);
            if (!doRequest(session, request, response))
            {
                std::cerr << "Invalid username or password" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception& exc)
    {
        std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my .pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp


POCO_HOME = "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL"

# SEE http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23655-Does-Qt-Creator-understand-debug-release-scopes-in-pro-files
# OR http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30430-How-to-set-pro-file-about-debug-and-release
####
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
CONFIG -= debug release
CONFIG += debug
}

CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
CONFIG -= debug release
CONFIG += release
}
####

debug {
POCO_DEBUG = d
}

release {
POCO_DEBUG =
}

INCLUDEPATH += "$${POCO_HOME}\include"
INCLUDEPATH += "$${POCO_HOME}"
LIBS += $${POCO_HOME}\lib\libPocoNetd.a $${POCO_HOME}\lib\libPocoFoundationd.a $${POCO_HOME}\lib\libPocoUtild.a
```

and the build errors:

```
05:21:46: Running build steps for project download...
05:21:46: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
05:21:46: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/justin/Documents/Qt/download-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug'
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\download.exe debug/main.o  C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoFoundationd.a C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoUtild.a 
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/justin/Documents/Qt/download-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Offset (893751156) greater than or equal to (null) size (4954657).
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketAddress.o):SocketAddress.cpp:(.text+0x743): undefined reference to `ntohs@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '13637', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketAddress.o):SocketAddress.cpp:(.text+0x956): undefined reference to `htons@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '20039', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketAddress.o):SocketAddress.cpp:(.text+0xc5e): undefined reference to `getservbyname@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11075', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketAddress.o):SocketAddress.cpp:(.text+0xc7b): undefined reference to `ntohs@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Offset (3968946036) greater than or equal to (null) size (4954657).
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(IPAddress.o):IPAddress.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Poco3Net15IPv4AddressImpl10isLoopbackEv[Poco::Net::IPv4AddressImpl::isLoopback() const]+0x13): undefined reference to `ntohl@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '60561', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(IPAddress.o):IPAddress.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Poco3Net15IPv4AddressImpl11isMulticastEv[Poco::Net::IPv4AddressImpl::isMulticast() const]+0x13): undefined reference to `ntohl@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '20039', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(IPAddress.o):IPAddress.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Poco3Net15IPv4AddressImpl11isLinkLocalEv[Poco::Net::IPv4AddressImpl::isLinkLocal() const]+0x13): undefined reference to `ntohl@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11075', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(IPAddress.o):IPAddress.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Poco3Net15IPv4AddressImpl11isSiteLocalEv[Poco::Net::IPv4AddressImpl::isSiteLocal() const]+0x13): undefined reference to `ntohl@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11828', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(IPAddress.o):IPAddress.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Poco3Net15IPv4AddressImpl13isWellKnownMCEv[Poco::Net::IPv4AddressImpl::isWellKnownMC() const]+0x13): undefined reference to `ntohl@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '50', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(IPAddress.o):IPAddress.cpp:(.text$_ZNK4Poco3Net15IPv4AddressImpl13isLinkLocalMCEv[Poco::Net::IPv4AddressImpl::isLinkLocalMC() const]+0x13): more undefined references to `ntohl@4' follow
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '25458', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(IPAddress.o):IPAddress.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Poco3Net15IPv4AddressImpl5parseERKSs[Poco::Net::IPv4AddressImpl::parse(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)]+0x27): undefined reference to `inet_addr@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Offset (2427096948) greater than or equal to (null) size (4954657).
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `accept@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '37034', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x2c2): undefined reference to `connect@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '20039', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x3c1): undefined reference to `connect@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11075', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x641): undefined reference to `connect@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11828', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x74c): undefined reference to `bind@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '50', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x8bc): undefined reference to `listen@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '25458', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x910): undefined reference to `closesocket@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '25455', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x983): undefined reference to `shutdown@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '18804', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0xa15): undefined reference to `shutdown@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11884', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0xaa7): undefined reference to `shutdown@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '112', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0xb46): undefined reference to `send@16'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '19804', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0xc0a): undefined reference to `recv@16'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '22343', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0xd58): undefined reference to `sendto@24'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '31091', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0xe37): undefined reference to `recvfrom@24'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11825', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0xfb2): undefined reference to `send@16'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '28520', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x1237): undefined reference to `select@20'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '27228', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x1672): undefined reference to `getsockname@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '26996', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x1744): undefined reference to `getpeername@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '28528', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x199f): undefined reference to `setsockopt@20'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '12589', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x1c41): undefined reference to `getsockopt@20'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '13870', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x2167): undefined reference to `socket@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '29797', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x21ab): undefined reference to `ioctlsocket@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '21700', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text+0x21e5): undefined reference to `ioctlsocket@12'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '0', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(SocketImpl.o):SocketImpl.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Poco3Net10SocketImpl9lastErrorEv[Poco::Net::SocketImpl::lastError()]+0x7): undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Offset (2639866316) greater than or equal to (null) size (4954657).
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(Socket.o):Socket.cpp:(.text+0x4ee): undefined reference to `select@20'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '40281', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(Socket.o):Socket.cpp:(.text+0x64e): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '20039', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(Socket.o):Socket.cpp:(.text+0x722): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11075', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(Socket.o):Socket.cpp:(.text+0x7fe): undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: Offset (1197756532) greater than or equal to (null) size (4954657).
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo@16'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '18276', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '20039', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to `getnameinfo@28'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11075', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0x23b): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo@16'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '11828', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo@4'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '50', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0x5eb): undefined reference to `gethostname@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '25458', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0xb50): undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '21326', this reader only handles version 2 and 3 information.
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home\justin\poco-1.4.6\_INSTALL\lib\libPocoNetd.a(DNS.o):DNS.cpp:(.text+0xc18): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug\download.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
05:21:47: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project download (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: How about `LIBS += -lws2_32` (for winsock2)?

Comment: I added `-lws2_32` and it builds now but it stops responding right when I run it.
Qt's debugger isn't doing anything, but when I debug it with VS it says: `Unhandled exception at 0x004630e6 in download.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0049fdd0.`
@Anton-Kovalenko

Comment: Well, try to debug it and post another question when you're stuck.

Comment: Qt's debugger isn't doing anything, but when I debug it with VS it says: `Unhandled exception at 0x004630e6 in download.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0049fdd0.`
@AntonKovalenko

Comment: Post another question (be prepared to show your code, etc). I can't help on this one, I'm not even a Windows user.