# Build poco libraries with custom linkflags

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, poco-libraries, ldflags

I'm trying to build the [poco libraries](http://pocoproject.org/) with [mudflap](http://www.stlinux.com/devel/debug/mudflap) support, which requires extra compilation and link flags. I have figured out that the `POCO_FLAGS` variable in `config.make` controls the compiler flags. How do I specify link flags?

The documentation [here](http://pocoproject.org/docs/99150-GMakeBuildNotes.html) talks about `LINKFLAGS`, `LINKFLAGS32`, and `LINKFLAGS64`, but I cannot figure out how to specify these, either by using `./configure` or by modifying the `config.make` file.

---

Edit:

I tried setting the environment variable `LINKFLAGS`, but this had no effect.

Comment: Those would seem to be environment variables you set before running the build (possibly before running `./configure`) and that influence the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned looking for a simple way to specify poco's linkflags. I ended up removing the libs (`rm -rf $POCO_ROOT/lib`) and running `make` to get the output of the linker step that poco's build system runs to build the libraries. I copied the output into a file and manually added in the linkflags that I needed. I also had to change the `make[1]: Entering directory...` lines to `cd ...`. I then ran the file as a bash script. All seems to be working. If someone posts a simpler way to do this involving the configure script or environment variables or hacking the makefile, I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the last stable version (1.4.6p4), you should look at **poco-1.4.6p4\build\config** directory and edit your compiler configuration there.

I think this is what you are looking for.

Take a look at this link:
[Compile Poco with MinGW on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637797/compile-poco-with-mingw-on-windows/14647307#14647307)

Regards.